# I am studying the arithmetic of remainders and modular congruence

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to understand an exercise that asks to determine the remainder of 40000 by 13
I have the resolution of the exercise, but I'm not understanding a part of it

1º) Search for the closest multiple of 13 to 40000 which is 39000
2º) Write the congruence: this: 39000\equiv 0\pmod 13
3º) Summation property
39000 + 1000\equiv 0 + 1000\pmod 13
40000\equiv 1000\pmod13

4º)property: if a\equiv b\pmod n  and b\equiv c\pmod n so a\equiv c\pmod n

5º) 390\equiv 0\pmod 13
390.2\equiv 0.2\pmod 13
780\equiv 0\pmod 13
780+130\equiv 0+130\pmod 13
910\equiv 130\pmod 13\equiv 0\pmod 13
910+90\equiv 0+90\pmod 13
1000\equiv 90\ pmod 13

6º) Reduce more, as 6.13=78 for 90 there are 12 more to go (90 = 6 x 13 + 12):
90\equiv 12\ pmod 13

40000\equiv 1000\equiv 90\equiv 12\pmod 13

Remainder = 12

And I didn't understand from step 5 on, I don't know where those numbers came from

And I didn't understand from step 5, as 390≡0(mod1)3
390
≡
0
(
mod
1
)
3
why multiply by 2? 390.2≡0.2(mod3)
390.2
≡
0.2
(
mod
3
)
And then you find 780≡0(mod1)3
780
≡
0
(
mod
1
)
3
Next step is 780+130≡0+130(mod1)3
780
+
130
≡
0
+
130
(
mod
1
)
3
Gave 910≡130(mod1)3≡0(mod1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You should add `$` signs before and after Mathjax code, like `$39000 \equiv 0 \pmod 13$`.

Comment: This is just long division.

Comment: And I didn't understand from step 5, as $390\equiv 0\pmod 13$ why multiply by 2?                    $390.2\equiv 0.2\pmod 3$
And then you find $780\equiv0\pmod 13$
Next step is $780+130\equiv0+130\pmod 13$
Gave $910\equiv130\pmod13\equiv 0\pmod13 $

Comment: Just as in step 2 from $13\equiv 0\pmod {13}$ to $13\cdot 3000\equiv 0\cdot3000\pmod{13}$: why multiply by $3000$? Because $1000$ is closer to $780$ than to $390$, while both $780$ and $390$ are multiples of $13$ that are convenient enough for the author.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail, how do i get to 390?

Comment: $390 = 13\cdot 30$. I would guess it's because $390$ is a multiple of $13$ that's easy and convenient for the author. No carry when performing $13\cdot 3$, and just a left shift when performing $39\cdot 10$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to parse your formatting easily, so I'll just work through the problem. I hope it helps.

Begin by finding the closest multiple of $13$ to $40000$. You identified that as $39000$ but that's actually not true; the closest multiple of $13$ is $39988$. This is because $13×3076=39988$. Since $40000-39988=12$ and $12\lt13$, this is your answer. $40000 \equiv 12 \mod(13)$.

But let's try it your way, working with $39000$ as an initial multiple of $13$. This means that $40000=13×3000+1000$, so the question now is to find the remainder of $1000$ by $13$. Let's forget about finding the closest multiple of $13$ and pick an easy one instead. Let's go with $13×30=390$. $1000$ can be written as $13×30+610$, so the goalpost has shifted to finding the remainder of $610$. Using $390$ again, $610 = 13×30 + 220$. Unfortunately, since $220 \lt 390$, we cannot use $13×30$ any more. How about $13×15$ instead? That's equal to $195$, so that works: $220 = 13×15 + 25$. Now we're at the last step. The remainder of $25$ by $13$ is $12$ since $25 = 1×13 +12$. As you can see, this is the same answer obtained with the first method.